# bad file descriptor python server

Tags: python, sockets, handle

I want to call a method inside the handle function of a server to execute it as a new thread. I want to pass as argument the request, as follows:

```
class serviceData(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):

        def dataTransfer(req):
            data = 'dummy'

            while len(data):              
                  #data = self.request.recv(1024)
                  data = req.recv(1024)
                  print str(data)

                  result = 'hi'


                  req.sendall(str(result))            

            print "Client exited"
            req.close()


        try:
            print "Client connected with ", self.client_address
            thread.start_new_thread( dataTransfer, (self.request, ) )
        except Exception, e:
            print e
            print "Error: unable to start thread"
```

I obtain the following error:

```
data = req.recv(1024)
File "usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py" line 170, in dummy
  raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Anyone knows what I am doing bad?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Mixing socket server and threads with `ThreadedTCPServer`. So:

```
class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass

server = ThreadedTCPServer( ('', 1520), service )
server.serve_forever()
```

In this way, `def handle(self):  ......`
creates a new thread for each new connection.